# Submit form to iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, file-upload, submit

Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong in the following code that the form is not being submit to the iframe?

```
$(function() {
    $(".preview").click(function() {
        $('#sliderimage').wrap('<form action="/index/upload.php" method="post" id="imageform" target="imageupload" />');
        $('#imageform').submit();
        $('#sliderimage').unwrap();
        return false;
    });
});​


<iframe style="display: none;" name="imageupload" id="imageupload"></iframe>
<input type="file" id="sliderimage" name="sliderimage">
<input type="button" class="preview" value="Preview">
```

Comment: How do you know it's not being submitted to the iframe? It appears to me you're missing an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form, also switch `type` for `method` in the form tag

Comment: What happens? Does the page refreshes? Goes to upload.php? Or nothing happens? Have you tried disabling the display:none, on iframe? See what goes to the iframe, if anything?

Comment: I know the form isn't being submit because upload.php reads <?php echo "run"; ?> and the iframe never contains the string run meaning it wasn't submit.

Comment: the iframe results are `<?php echo "run";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems I see right away, not sure if they will solve the issue or not.

You have set the 'type' to `post`. this attribute should be `method`.

as well you need to set the enctype on the form.

```
$(function() {
    $(".preview").click(function() {
        $('#sliderimage').wrap('<form action="/index/upload.php" method="post" id="imageform" target="imageupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" />');
        $('#imageform').submit();
        $('#sliderimage').unwrap();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

## EDIT

The code above is a direct cut and paste from your source.... this means the 'hidden'(â€‹) character jsfiddle pastes into your javascript is also there. remove it and you js will function. to do this simply backspace at the end of your js code once.

Comment: Thanks, I made these changes, however it doesn't fix it.

Comment: see my update and http://rlemon.com/example.html working example, the mystery character strikes again!